# Troubleshooting Firefox and VLC Mozilla plugin

Tags: 10.04, firefox, vlc, troubleshooting

I may be reaching here, but I figured this form would be worth a shot.  I'm working with our new HP "ThinPro" thin clients based on Ubuntu 10.04, but a very stripped down version of it.  Its running Firefox 8 and I was able to get VLC 1.1.13 with the Mozilla plugin installed.

I have a customer in my company that is looking to use our thin clients to stream video to these devices.  They are looking to purchase a streaming product to do so.  The above configuration works when I test on other web sites, but this purchased solution doesn't quite work with our configuration.  After some coaxing, they said they tested this on a Linux OS, but not with what we have.  They tested on Redhat with VLC 2.0 and that's what they say they will support.

Here is my question:
I hope to see what the core issue is and why there solution will not work and hopefully get them to make some code changes so it does.  When I click on there video, the plugin starts up, but then just sits there.  No video runs.  I can open VLC, Media > Open Network Stream... and paste in the URL to the mp4 and the video plays fine.  So the issue steams to be in the Mozilla plugin.

I found there is a debug mode for Firefox, but it disables all plugins, which is not what I need.  Are there any other logs that exists or that I can enable to tell me what might not be working correctly?

Comment: Can someone confirm if this issue persists with newer version of the mozilla plugin/firefox/vlc/ubuntu?

Comment: 10.04 is quite old. Try a newer version of Ubuntu and report back please. 14.04 just came out.